# Is there an option to ion-toggle change a variable value with its properties

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ionic-framework, toggle

I cant make a variable change using a function with ion-toggle, but i want to know if theres any way with ion-toggle properties, to change the value of an variable when the the toggle is pressed (without using functions).

I tried checked, value, change, ngModel, but i cant make a variable to change when the button is pressed.

```
  <ion-toggle slot="end" 
checked="test" 
[ngModel]="test" 
(click)="changeTest()" ></ion-toggle>
```

The variable test is by default true, so the button starts active, and i want to change the value of test when i press the button, without using functions, because with functions i alrady did it (changeTest())

Thanks

Comment: Did you try `[(ngModel)]="test" `?

Comment: Yup,it doesnt change

Comment: Did you import `import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';`?

Comment: No,because on the same file, there are others ionchange and ngmodels and they work

Answer (score 2):

use the ionChange event

```
<ion-toggle slot="end" 
checked="test" 
[ngModel]="test" 
(ionChange)="changeTest()" ></ion-toggle>
```

Comment: If you want two way binding (so the component is updated on value change) you'll want to use `[(ngModel)]="test"` https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel#template-variable-references